# Add a custom meta box on order edit pages and display it on the customer order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta-boxes, orders

In WooCommerce, would like to add a custom meta box on WooCommerce Admin order pages.

In this box, I just want to enter a tracking number in a text field that saves to that order.

Then on the customer view order page, I would like to display a button that opens a modal with tracking information. The modal will just pull in an iframe with a URL that has the tracking number at the end.

The courier company I'm using has a tracking website so for now I'm just going to display the iframe in the modal using the tracking number that was entered on the admin order page.

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

How do I save and use it?

I have this so far:

```
// Add meta box
function tcg_tracking_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'tcg-tracking-modal',
        'The Courier Guy Tracking',
        'tcg_meta_box_callback',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'tcg_tracking_box' );

// Callback
function tcg_meta_box_callback( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $text = isset( $values['tcg_tracking_box'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['tcg_tracking_box'][0] ) : '';
    echo '<input type="text" name="tcg_tracking_box" id="tcg_tracking_box" value="' . $text . '" />';
}

// Saving
add_action( 'save_post', 'tcg_tracking_box_save' );
function tcg_tracking_box_save( $post_id )
{

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways. I have corrected your code and added a custom hooked function at the end that will display this custom field value in my Account Order view pages:

```
// Add meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'tcg_tracking_box' );
function tcg_tracking_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'tcg-tracking-modal',
        'The Courier Guy Tracking',
        'tcg_meta_box_callback',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}

// Callback
function tcg_meta_box_callback( $post )
{
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tracking_box', true );
    $text = ! empty( $value ) ? esc_attr( $value ) : '';
    echo '<input type="text" name="tracking_box" id="tcg_tracking_box" value="' . $text . '" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="tracking_box_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';
}

// Saving
add_action( 'save_post', 'tcg_save_meta_box_data' );
function tcg_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // Only for shop order
    if ( 'shop_order' != $_POST[ 'post_type' ] )
        return $post_id;

    // Check if our nonce is set (and our cutom field)
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'tracking_box_nonce' ] ) && isset( $_POST['tracking_box'] ) )
        return $post_id;

    $nonce = $_POST[ 'tracking_box_nonce' ];

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Checking that is not an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user’s permissions (for 'shop_manager' and 'administrator' user roles)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Saving the data
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_tracking_box', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'tracking_box' ] ) );
}

// Display To My Account view Order
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'tcg_display_tracking_box_in_order_view', 10, 1 );
function tcg_display_tracking_box_in_order_view( $order )
{
    $tracking_box = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_tracking_box', true );
    // Output Tracking box
    if( ! empty( $tracking_box ) && is_account_page() )
        echo '<p>Tracking box: '. $tracking_box .'</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on woocommerce version 3+ and works

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It works like a charm!!!! I added it in a plugin and works perfectly. Thanks!